# Receiving 404 error with Restlet and SpringServerServlet

Tags: spring, restlet

I'm just starting with Restlet and I'm using the version 2.0-M3.  I'm trying to use Spring within a web application.  When I try to access the url /hello within my application, I am receiving a 404 error.  Here are the parts of my code:

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.component</param-name>
            <param-value>helloComponent</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

ServerResource:

```
public class MyResource extends ServerResource {
@Get
public String getResource()  {
    return "Hello World!";
}
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="helloComponent" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringComponent">
    <property name="defaultTarget" ref="helloAppliction" />
</bean>

<bean id="helloAppliction" class="MyApplication">
    <property name="root" ref="router" />
</bean>

<!--  Define the router -->
<bean name="router" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringBeanRouter"/>

<!-- Define all the routes -->
<bean name="/hello" id="helloResource" class="MyServerResource" scope="prototype" autowire="byName" />
```

Here is the error message in the log:

```
Oct 12, 2013 11:34:59 PM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2013-10-12        23:34:59        127.0.0.1       -       127.0.0.1       8080    GET     /mywebapp/hello  -       404     330     -       1       http:
//localhost:8080        Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0    -
```

Can someone tell me if you see anything wrong?

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 0):

I think you posted on the discussion board of Restlet as well? I'll answer the same as I did there.

You don't attach the "/hello" path to the router. Your router has no routes, and thus will always give a 404.